# How to link pictures to an entry in a database?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have my pictures saved in a package in the res folder.
I want to link these pictures to entries in my sqlLite database.

What is the best way to do this?
what should I save in the database to get this picture and how to access it?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the incremental ID you use for the row in your database as name for your image, you can keep track of the original filename in your database if you want it for further use, like user downloading and so on.

Using this technique, you're sure not to have files with the same name.
You can store the images without file extension if you want.